# Merge two tables in R

Tags: r, merge, rbind

I have two tables, which have the same column names, number of rows and columns:

```
ID     Q1        Q2
1      aa        bb
2      cc        12
3      q         z


ID     Q1        Q2
1      A         B
2      p         l_
3      23        r
```

I would like to have in the next table merged those above columns with both context and separated by \n, like this:

```
  ID     Q1        Q2
  1      aa        bb
         A         B
  2      cc        12
         p         l_
  3      q         z
         23        r
```

I have tried, `merge`, `rbind`, `cbind`, but I didn't get any good results. 
Any ides how to do this?

Required result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrGxw.png)

Comment: What determines which of the two rows actually gets assigned an `ID` value, and which row does not?

Comment: What do you want in the blank spaces where ID was duplicated? Do you want ID to be a character column and have an empty string there? You can't have empty numeric values - NA is another possibility,

Comment: short answer - rbind them and then fixup any of ID that are `duplicated(d$ID)`

Comment: Are you trying to get some sort of printed output?

Comment: I would like to get the table with the same number of rows, so for example for ID: 1, I get one merged cell Q1: contained: 'aa' and A etc.

Comment: You do realise that even putting `\n` in the elements *wont* make it print out like this?

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
> d1
  ID Q1 Q2
1  1 aa bb
2  2 cc 12
3  3  q  z
> d2
  ID Q1 Q2
1  1  A  B
2  2  p l_
3  3 23  r
```

row-bind:

```
> d = rbind(d1, d2)
```

sort by ID:

```
> d = d[order(d$ID),]
```

replace duplicated ID by something, eg NA:

```
> d$ID[duplicated(d$ID)]=NA
```

job done:

```
> d
  ID Q1 Q2
1  1 aa bb
4 NA  A  B
2  2 cc 12
5 NA  p l_
3  3  q  z
6 NA 23  r
>
```

If you want to create merged cells with `\n` separating them, then this:

```
> cbind(ID=d1$ID, setNames(do.call(cbind.data.frame,lapply(c("Q1","Q2"), function(n){paste(d1[[n]],d2[[n]],sep="\n")})),c("Q1","Q2")))
  ID    Q1     Q2
1  1 aa\nA  bb\nB
2  2 cc\np 12\nl_
3  3 q\n23   z\nr
```

Comment: But I would like to keep the number of rows. Attached image shows the required result